# File not being uploaded online (offline/local works)

Tags: php, laravel

Case: Uploading avatars. This is working offline on my localhost, but after putting it online to 000webhost hosting provider, this does not work anymore. The file is NOT being uploaded but Laravel does not returns any error. Any idea to solve this?Thankyou.

This is my controller:

```
   if ($request->hasFile('avatar'))
            {
                $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
                $avatar = $request->file('avatar'); // in here 
                $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalName();
                $path = base_path();
                $path = str_replace("gsm-cp","public_html",$path);
                $destinationPath = $path.'/img/avatars';
                $avatar->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                $user->avatar = $filename;  
                $user->save();
                  
            }
```

This is my config/filesystems.php

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
...
```

Comment: Open browser console and see if there's any error? One possible cause of this is just file you are uploading too big and the server rejects. Try smaller size picture and comment

Comment: A sidenote, but `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);` can simply be `$user = Auth::user();`

Comment: @SviesusAlus the size just 15.2 kb and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by using `storeAs()`, as well as replacing `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);` with `$user = Auth::user();`.

`storeAs()` takes a path, the filename to store, and takes an optional array, which can for example specify the disk -- here, we're using the public one. This would store the images in `./storage/app/public/avatars/1597750757_1.jpg` for user with ID 1.

```php
if ($request->hasFile('avatar'))
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
    $filename = time().'_'.$user->id.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = $avatar->storeAs("/avatars/", $filename, ['disk' => 'public']);
    $user->avatar = $filename;
    $user->save();
}
```

You may alternatively want to store down the path, and not just the filename. The `storeAs()` method returns the full path to the image (including its name).

- [File Storage docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-uploads)

Comment: I try, and does'nt work. The file not uploaded in the storage.